# Caliburn.Micro, how to access the actual viewmodel used from within the view

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I want to access the actual viewmodel that is **currently used** from within the view (code-behind). In the bootstrapper I have the viewmodel set to perrequest so I cannot use IoC.Get<..ViewModel>(); (nor do I want to change this behavior).

Basically, I'm looking for the equivalent of the GetView from the Screen, but then the other way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**DataContext**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you the current ViewModel which is applied as DataContext of view.

```
// Get you the object of ViewModel.
var viewModelInstance = DataContext;

// Or typecast to exact instance what you intend to use.
MyViewModel vm = DataContext as MyViewModel;
```

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Totally forgot about that property. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the `DataContext` will have a value assigned to it once the `View` has been loaded. For example you can access to it in the loaded event of the `View`.